# PHP create array from another array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array which I have received from an API.

```
object(stdClass)#19498 (4) {
  ["success"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["quoteId"]=>
  int(0011)
  ["abcValue"]=>
  float(00)
  ["priceResponse"]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    object(stdClass)#19502 (9) {
      ["priceId"]=>
      int(1263)
      ["fPrice"]=>
      float(37.14)
      ["grossPrice"]=>
      float(44.7)
      ["priceType"]=>
      string(2) "ABC"
    }
    [1]=>
    object(stdClass)#19501 (10) {
      ["priceId"]=>
      int(1263)
      ["fPrice"]=>
      float(37.14)
      ["grossPrice"]=>
      float(44.7)
      ["priceType"]=>
      string(2) "ABC"
    }
    [2]=>
    object(stdClass)#19500 (8) {
      ["priceId"]=>
      int(1266)
      ["fPrice"]=>
      float(550.14)
      ["grossPrice"]=>
      float(544.7)
      ["priceType"]=>
      string(2) "DEF"
    }
  }
}
```

I want to loop through the array to add another object in `PriceResponse` i.e customPrice and also delete some objects from the array like `fPrice`, `priceType` etc. The best way I figured to do this was to create another array. However I can't seem to get it working:

PHP:

```
$output_array = json_decode($output);
$modified_array = array();
$priceResultArray = array();

foreach($output_array as $j => $item) {

    foreach($output_array->priceResponse as $i => $field) {
        $percent =  $field->grossPrice * 10 / 100;
        $customPrice =  $field->grossPrice + $percent;


        $priceResultArray['priceId'] = $field->priceId;
        $priceResultArray['customPrice'] = $customPrice;

    }

    $modified_array['success'] = $output_array->success;
    $modified_array['quoteId'] = $output_array->quoteId;
    $modified_array['priceResponse'] = $priceResultArray;

}
var_dump($modified_array);
```

This is the output of the modified array - it only shows the last result of the priceResultArray:

```
array(3) {
  ["success"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["quoteId"]=>
  int(0011)
  ["priceResult"]=>
  array(5) {
    ["priceId"]=>
    int(1266)
    ["customPrice"]=>
    float(599.17)
  }
}
```

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: `$output_array` is an object, not an array, why are you looping over it?

Comment: the only array is `$output_array->price_response`.

Comment: Why do you think the best way is to create a new array? Why not just add and delete the properties in the existing array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the outer loop. `$output_array` is a single object, not an array. You're looping over the properties, but never doing anything with `$j` or `$item`.

And instead of creating a new array, you can simply modify the objects in the original `priceResponse` array.

```
$output_array = json_decode($output);
foreach ($output_array->priceResponse as $field) {
    $percent =  $field->grossPrice * 10 / 100;
    $customPrice =  $field->grossPrice + $percent;
    $field->customPrice = $customPrice;
    unset($field->fPrice);
    unset($field->priceType);
    unset($field->grossPrice);
}
```

Comment: While this code didn't work for me (`var_dump` returns the old output), you rightly pointed out that I mistook the output which was an object for an array all this time. >.< I'll try again.

Comment: I'm not sure why it didn't work. I just did a simple test and I think it should work.

Answer (score 1):

You have such output because you put values inside the same keys within your loop.
You should create new object on each loop interation.
Checkout this code:

```html
$output_array = json_decode($output);
$modified_array = array();
$priceResultArray = array();

foreach($output_array as $j => $item) {

    foreach($output_array->priceResponse as $i => $field) {
        $percent =  $field->grossPrice * 10 / 100;
        $customPrice =  $field->grossPrice + $percent; 

        $singlePriceResult = array();
        $singlePriceResult['priceId'] = $field->priceId;
        $singlePriceResult['customPrice'] = $customPrice;

        $priceResultArray[] = $singlePriceResult;
    }

    $modified_array['success'] = $output_array->success;
    $modified_array['quoteId'] = $output_array->quoteId;
    $modified_array['priceResponse'] = $priceResultArray;

}
var_dump($modified_array);
```

Comment: While this did show all of the priceResultArray output, it repeated it to the count of `priceResponse` array.

Comment: @input yes, but what behaviour was supposed?

Comment: It's repeating all of the priceResultArray objects (in the above output, thrice). It should show _all_ of the priceResultArray objects just once.

Comment: @input quite wierd that you ask such easy questions, it can be fixed without    asking questions on stackoverflow